# JavaScript WebSockets not working on mobile?

Tags: javascript, mobile, tcp, websocket

I have a webpage that tries to connect to a WebSocket Node.js server, and it works fine on desktop, but not on mobile.

Here is the server:

```
var websocket = require("websocket").server;
var http = require("http");

var port = 12348;

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    //console.log("server > received request for: " + request.url);
    //response.writeHead(404);
    //response.end();
});

server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("listening on port " + port);
});

socket = new websocket({
    httpServer: server,
});

socket.on("request", function (request) {
    var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);
    console.log("connection accepted");

    connection.send("Welcome to BrD");
    connection.send('Type "brdhelp" for help');

    connection.on("message", 
    function (data) {
        if (data.type === "utf8") {
            var message = data.utf8Data;

            console.log("client > " + message);
        }
    });

    connection.on("close", 
    function (reasonCode, description) {
        console.log("server > " + connection.remoteAddress + " disconnected.");
    });
});
```

Here is the client on the webpage:

```
//Enables mozilla's built-in WebSocket if it's available
window.WebSocket = window.WebSocket || window.MozWebSocket;
var pageHeight = window.innerHeight ||document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight || document.body.offsetHeight;

connectToServer();

function connectToServer () {
    connection = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:12348");

    connection.onopen = 
    function () {
        addResponseLine("connected to server, type \"help\" for client help");
    };

    connection.onerror = 
    function (error) {

    };

    connection.onmessage = 
    function (message) {
        addResponseLine("server > " + message.data);
    };

    connection.onclose = 
    function () {
        addLine("disconnected from server, type \"reconnect\" to reconnect");
    };
}

function checkInput () {
    var event = window.event || event.which;

    //When user presses enter, add input to <p> and clear the input
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        addLine(document.getElementById("textinput").value);
        document.getElementById("textinput").value = "";
    }

    //Set height of input TODO: do this when document loads
    var newHeight = ((pageHeight - 20) - document.getElementById("consoletext").style.height);
    if (document.getElementById("textinput").style.height != newHeight) {
        document.getElementById("textinput").style.height = newHeight + "px";
    }
}

//This function is for outpput to the user, it doesn't check for commands
function addResponseLine (line) {
    var newText = document.createTextNode(line);
    var br = document.createElement("br");
    document.getElementById("consoletext").appendChild(newText);
    document.getElementById("consoletext").appendChild(br);
}

//This function is for adding the user's input to the <p>, it can also check for commands
function addLine (line) {
    if (line != "") {
        line = line.toLowerCase();
        var newText = document.createTextNode(line);
        var br = document.createElement("br");
        document.getElementById("consoletext").appendChild(newText);
        document.getElementById("consoletext").appendChild(br);

        connection.send(line);
    }
}
```

Like I said, everything works fine on desktop, but not mobile.

Comment: What mobile browser are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

are you sure that the line connection = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:12348"); is correct?
iwould expect something like

```
connection = new WebSocket("ws://xxx.yyy.zzz.kkk:12348");
```

expecially if the nodejs part is in you localhost....

Comment: Oh Yeah!! That definitely can be a problem here!